# Syntax error in .runsettings file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to include a function in the code coverage using the following line in the .runsettings file:

```
<Function>^Fort\.CMS\.CMSPages\.BlogModerator\.GetBlogComments$</Function>
```

In the .runsettings file in MSTest project for unit testing. But it gives a syntax error, what I am doing wrong here?

Here

```
**Fort.CMS.CMSPages**  is the *namespace*
**BlogModerator** is the *Class Name*.
**GetBlogComments** is the *function name*
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj159530.aspx) your function declaration should aslo include parameters.
Try this

`<Function>^Fort\.CMS\.CMSPages\.BlogModerator\.GetBlogComments\(\)$</Function>`

in case method hasn't parameters.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA can you try \(.* instead \(\)$ at the end

Comment: can update the entire line, I am little confused what to replace

Comment: <Function>^Fort\.CMS\.CMSPages\.BlogModerator\.GetBlogComments\(.*</Function>   - and "\" before "(" - "\" isn't shown in message